# jQueryUI datepicker not functioning

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've been working on a project and I wanted to use jqueryUI datepicker, it's not a unfamilliar action to me but now with laravel blade templating it doesn't work. I tried a lot of things but I seem not to be getting to a solution. If someone knows the answer, I'd be glad if that's shared with me and anyone else who could be dealing with same sort of problem. Here's the block of code.

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQueryUI CSS -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        <main class="py-4">
            <div class="container">

            <!-- on this place where datepicker is, it's "@yield('content')" -->
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

            </div>
        </main>

    </div>

    <!-- jQueryUI scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    } );
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue and the fix for me was taking out the second include of jQuery at the end of the document. jQuery gets loaded in with app.js in the header and the second include for that overwrites the first include and causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine, there is only a missing **https:** in style link:

`<!-- jQueryUI CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running locally, you need to either download or include jquery-ui.css with http, something like

```
<!-- jQueryUI CSS -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

When you run locally without http:// it turns url to something like `file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

Answer (score 0):

I use This...I hope it helps.

```
<!-- jQueryUI scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames:['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior'
    });

});
</script>
```